# Пересечение со списком в SQL

Tags: sql

Есть запрос, в WHERE которого приходится делать ещё один запрос. Нужно вернуть соответствие условию в том случае, если результат запроса пересекается со списком (“1", "2", "3"). Или не пересекается. Упрощённый запрос для примера:

```
SELECT table1_val1 FROM table1
WHERE 
(SELECT table2_val1 FROM table2 WHERE table2_val3=table1_val3) INTERSECT (“1", "2", "3")
```

Здесь очевидно неверное использование INTERSECT. Как это сделать корректно? Для варианта пересечения и не пересечения?

Comment: давайте вы лучше на примере данных покажите что есть и что хотите получить. А еще лучше если при этом конкретную укажите

Comment: Также укажите используемую СУБД. И, полагаю, проблема в том, что эти значения: 1, 2, 3 - не забиты в запрос, а должны поступить извне?

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Особенно пункты 5 и 3.

Comment: *Здесь очевидно неверное использование INTERSECT.* Да, INTERSECT ожидает два набора данных, тогда как список в скобках на набор не тянет вот совсем. Но даже будь там ещё один запрос - INTERSECT возвращает набор данных, который не может быть приведён к булеву типу, то есть по-любому будет ошибка. В таком случае должно быть `WHERE EXISTS (subquery1 INTERSECT subquery2)`. А вообще для проверки пересечения достаточно вульгарного EXISTS или INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

Формально так:

```
SELECT table1.val1 FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table2.val3=table1.val3
      AND table2.val1 IN (1, 2, 3)
    )
```

Comment: Упомянутый вами в комментарии `INNER JOIN` всё же выглядел бы короче и понятнее )

Comment: @CrazyElf JOIN требует конвертации списка в набор записей (SELECT UNION SELECT, либо VALUES, если версия позволяет), это длинно и некрасиво.. К тому же при правильной индексации WHERE EXISTS будет быстрее, особенно если процент выбираемых записей невелик.

Comment: А, я понял, это из-за того, что не 1 к 1 записи могут быть, вторую таблицу надо группировать как-то тогда и проще уж `exists` действительно написать.